# How to create and assign entity on form submission in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, formbuilder

I am new to Symfony2, but having a good time with it so far. I am attempting to design a tool that will generate contracts for us, based on input provided by the sales representative. The sales rep will choose a service on the form, and then enter the negotiated price.

I have three types of entities.

```
Contracts (id, name)
ContractService(contract_id, service_id, adjustedPrice)
Service(id, name)
```

I build my forms service field using the `entity` type to create a dropdown/select containing all of the possible services. However, I get an error when the form is submitted, because the Contract->setService expects a `ContractService` entity, but the form returns a `Service` type.

So I created a listener with a prePersist condition that executes a method that accepts a `Service` entity, and a `Contract` entity, and returns a `ContractService` entity.

I believe at this point I need to somehow swap the newly created `ContractService` in for the `Service` entity that the form returns, but I am not sure how to do that. It also seems like there may be a better way for going about this. Any help is appreciated, and if you need code examples or anything please let me know.

Comment: If i right understand you need to use [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Noquox. I had not read of the transformers so that was good information. It lead down a path that now has me believing I need an embedded form for the 'ContractService', instead of taking a piece of my 'Contract' form and trying to transform it into the creation of a 'ContractSolution'.